# error en la conexión de php con postgresql-10.9

Tags: postgresql, pdo, php7

al momento de ejecutar la conexión con la base de datos me sale el siguiente error 
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: la autentificación password falló para el usuario «www-data» FATAL: la autentificación password falló para el usuario «www-data»

Alguien sabe a que se debe esto y como lo puedo solucionar

Comment: [Una posible solucion a tu problema bro ](https://cstan.io/?p=6618)

Comment: Tengo la misma configuración en el archivo pg_hba.conf y también puedo entrar normalmente a las bases de datos en postgresql-10, no se que mas podría ser, pues el error persiste.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la.cadena de conexión que estás haciendo desde PHP para que te de ese error? Y si puedes compartir tu archivo pg_hba para poder analizar mejor